# how to solve this error with lambda and sorted method when i try to make sentiment analysis (POS or NEG text)?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis, feature-extraction, text-classification

Input code:

`best = sorted(word_scores.items(), key=lambda w, s: s, reverse=True)[:10000]`

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\python\test.py", line 78, in <module>
best = sorted(word_scores.items(), key=lambda w, s: s, reverse=True)[:10000]
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

---

How do I solve it?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of what your `word_scores` dictionary looks like?

Comment: this is a sup code of my code that represents the idea : pos_word_count = label_word_fd['pos'].N() **
neg_word_count = label_word_fd['neg'].N() **
total_word_count = pos_word_count + neg_word_count **
 
word_scores = {} **
 
for word, freq in word_fd.items():**
    pos_score = BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq(label_word_fd['pos'][word],
        (freq, pos_word_count), total_word_count) **
    neg_score = BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq(label_word_fd['neg'][word],
        (freq, neg_word_count), total_word_count) **
    word_scores[word] = pos_score + neg_score

Comment: each line of code separated by **

Comment: add your code in to question not in Comment..

Comment: i already added the code which i asked about but i just want to clarify the idea more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood the format of your `word_scores` dictionary correctly (that the keys are words and the values are integers representing scores), and you're simply looking to get an ordered list of words with the highest scores, it's as simple as this:

```
best = sorted(word_scores, key=word_scores.get, reverse=True)[:10000]
```

If you want to use a lambda to get an ordered list of tuples, where each tuple is a word and a score, and they are ordered by score, you can do the following:

```
best = sorted(word_scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:10000]
```

The difference between this and your original attempt is that I have passed one argument (x) to the lambda, and x is a tuple of length 2 - x[0] is the word and x[1] is the score. Since we want to sort by score, we use x[1].

Comment: i think it all about the syntax of lambda in python 3.6 , i will search a little bit more about it

Comment: i solve it , i just removed the argument w from the argument list ^_^ , thank you

Comment: Ah I just edited my answer with an alternative using a lambda, glad you solved it anyway.